# Как в кордате фильтровать данные по вхождению символов только с первых букв каждого слова?

Tags: objective-c, coredata

Как в кордате фильтровать данные по вхождению символов только с первых букв каждого слова? 
Чтобы по строке поиска **«ВИ»**

находило такие имена:
1 «**ВИ**ктор Бондарев»,
2 «Александр **ВИ**слоух»

и не находило такие:
3 «Петр Артемо**ВИ**ч»,
4 «э**ВИ**ль Карло**ВИ**ч»

Сейчас работает так, но нужно отбросить 3 и 4 варианты:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText];
NSArray *authors = [DAKAuthor MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: А пробовал: "name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@"? или "name BEGINSWITH[c] %@"

Comment: В предикатах можно использовать regex: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW9 . Только это ощутимо медленнее на больших объёмах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этой задачи лучше всего объединить BEGINSWITH и CONTAINS

```
NSString* searchTextWithSpase = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[c] %@ OR name BEGINSWITH[c] %@"
                                  , searchTextWithSpase, searchText];
NSArray *authors = [DAKAuthor MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Что бы находило с первых букв каждого слова ставь пробел перед searchText:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[c] %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", searchText]];
NSArray *authors = [DAKAuthor MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate];
```